# How to display the installed Zend Framework version on the command line?

Tags: version, zend-framework2, composer-php

I have a ZF2 based upon the [ZF2 Skeleton](https://github.com/zendframework/ZendSkeletonApplication). How can I find out, which ZF2 version is currently being used?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

With the Composer's `show` command in the root directory of the ([ZF2 Skeleton](https://github.com/zendframework/ZendSkeletonApplication) based) project:

```
$ cd /path/to/project/
$ php composer show --installed
...
zendframework/zendframework 2.1.4 Zend Framework 2
...
```

Answer (score 26):

As per [zend framework official site](https://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.version.reading.html), version can be retrieved with command

```
echo Zend_Version::getLatest();
```

So, to access PHP in Terminal run

```
php -a
```

then

```
echo "Zend engine version: " . zend_version();
```

and press enter button to get the version information something like

> Zend engine version: 2.6.0

Or check **VERSION** value in file **Zend/Version.php** if your project is using some specific version of zend framework.

Comment: The doc behind your link says: "The static method Zend_Version::getLatest() provides the version number of the *last stable release available for download* on the site » Zend Framework." — How is that what the OP asked, namely the version currently installed in the project?

Comment: Works like a charm! Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

If for whatever reason you didn't use `composer` to install ZF2 (come on! what's wrong with you, always use `composer` :)) you can run your app from the console to check the version:

```
$ cd <project_root>
$ php public/index.php
```

This assumes that `index.php` is your ZF2 front controller.

This will output something like:

```
Zend Framework 2.1.4 application
Usage:
```

Answer (score 3):

In Zend framework (3.0.0), try this:

```
die(zend_version());
```

Answer (score 3):

There seems to be quite a confusion between what is asked and what is the solution.

For instance, here at the same system;

'''php public/index.php'''

- results in "3.0.0"

'''die(zend_version());'''

- results in "3.2.0"

'''echo Zend_Version::getLatest();'''

- results in "1.12.20".

and

'''echo  Zend_Version::VERSION;'''

results in "1.12.20".

To get the version of the Zend Framework, written in PHP, as a web framework, use:

'''echo  Zend_Version::VERSION;'''

... As stated on the official page of the Zend Framework for web pages:

[Getting the Zend Framework Version - Zend_Version](https://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.version.reading.html)

Often is Zend Framework confused with The Zend Engine. The Zend Engine is the standard PHP interpreter, and is an open source scripting engine that interprets the PHP programming language.

If you like to get the version of the Zend Engine "inside" PHP, then use:

'''die(zend_version());'''

- results in "3.2.0"